# How to convert this PHP Facebook "Like status" App into C# (.NET)?

Tags: c#, php, facebook

This tutorial (http://bit.ly/hYEVYF) was helpful in familiarizing myself with C# & Visual Studio, but it accomplishes a different goal.

Here is the PHP code (which works perfectly):

```
<?php require 'lib/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook( array( 
  'appId'   => APP_ID,
  'secret'  => APP_SECRET,
  'cookie'  => true
) );

try {
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
  error_log( $e );
}

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$liked = $signed_request['page']['liked'];

?>

<?php
if ( $liked ) : ?>
  YOU LIKE US!
<?php else : ?>
  YOU DON'T LIKE US YET!
<?php endif; ?>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

Comment: It is to localized. may be hire someone.

Comment: You should use the .NET Facebook API (I bet there is one). I (we?) don't know if there is a 1-to-1 compatibility between the PHP Facebook API and .NET Facebook API..

Comment: I went down the route of creating this in pure JavaScript, but found out the hard way that it will prompt the user to "Allow application access". The above php code does not prompt the user for this. I could also easily convert this to ruby, but for this particular application it needs to be .NET. I *could* hire someone to do this but I would like to know how to do this myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).